# Slow update of reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, reputation-recalc

How come that newly earned reputation is not shown on e.g. the site overview page here at the StackExchange main site and on the specific sites ranking lists? It *is* shown in the top bar with the username.

And how long will it take for it to update fully onto all sites (which is the site itself and the StackExchange main site)?

Just wondering. Thanks.

Comment: The reputation is tallied in a heavily cached form.  Where small changes matter, such as for the user themselves, they are updated as changes occur.  Elsewhere the reputation is summed up once a day and stuffed into a table and used, so many areas are only once  day due to the heavy burden it would place on the database to sum the last 24 hours of reputation/voting/etc for all the users, for each page visit, so they can be properly ranked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been discussed on some other question, I'm just too lazy to find the duplicate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page is cached for about 10 minutes, and the reputation changes feeding into the user store backing this takes up to a minute or so to process those changes being fed in.