# I gave it "a couple of days", but reputation oddity persists

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-recalc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation display bug… Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again)

More than a week has passed since I posted [this question about my TeX-LaTeX reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145567/155793). It was fairly quickly dismissed as a duplicate of [another question related to caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103176/slow-update-of-reputation).

So I have waited for the reputation scores to settle. But nothing has changed in eight days; the numbers are exactly the same today. There must be more to this than caching.

**Update:**

Doing a "reputation recalc" did settle the scores (as suggested in a comment). But why was this necessary? When I posted this question, I wasn't aware that there was such a thing as recalculation.

Comment: Nah, most likely still caching. Often a reputation event (plus or minus) will trigger an update though. Perhaps you could try answering or editing something to get some rep? Not a solution of the problem of course, but in the past that has shown to wake some things up.

Comment: Where does it say that this can take a week or more to settle? Certainly not in the answer to the question that I am supposed to have duplicated.

Comment: Nowhere that I know of. As I said, I don't really know what the cause is. I only know what seems to have resolved it in the past.

Comment: Doing a rep. recalc on http://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation might settle things.

Comment: @Mat: Doing a recalc as you suggested seems to have fixed it. I did not know you could do that (or that you ever should need to).