# Meta reputation not accurate when viewed from other Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-recalc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation display bug… Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again)

My Meta SO score is 743. But it shows 738 when viewed from any other Stack Exchange site. I know it takes some time for all the sites to sync up but the day I reached 743 from 738 was 11 days back. I think the sync should have happened within this time. Or am I missing something?

Also, I noticed the scores of all other sites are syncing within a pretty small time span.

> [image]

**EDIT** As soon as this post was voted upon, my score on meta synced up with all sites! Curious to know what's happening here though.

Comment: Possibly related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146341/155793.